# How to tell tensorflow to use only one GPU, and if that GPU is already in use, then it is allowed to use the second GPU?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I have a workaround by using

```
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0"
```

And manually setting it to

```
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="1"
```

When I know I have already started a training with the first GPU. How can I automate this?